# Magento add Related products

Tags: magento, product

in Magento there is a section called "Related Products" that is automatically filled (only in my case?) and I'd like to add certain products to that list (to the related products).

I've tried looking around stackoverflow and other sites but it only explains how to REMOVE them and not add them.

How is that done?

Comment: Do you want to add related products block or add related products itself ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy The products themselves. I have the graphical part already.

Comment: So what is stopping you to add related products ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click 'reset filter' and all products should show up. Select the products you want and save and continue.